# How to setup CTS for android 11 on window

Tags: java, android, testing, mobile, cts

I find solution create .bat file and edit it with :

```
java -cp ddmlib-prebuilt.jar;tradefed-prebuilt.jar;hosttestlib.jar;cts-tradefed.jar -DCTS_ROOT=D:\ com.android.cts.tradefed.command.CtsConsole
```

It run for CTS 4.2 but not run for cts android 11. File .bat not work. I had replaced DCTS_ROOT path, but it not work too. I see the directory structure cts 4.2 and cts 11 are different

Comment: *but it not work* is not an error description. Please explain what it means

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: when i double click .bat file, prompt is blink in task bar but can not run and i can't receive any error

Comment: Can you give me some way to set up and run android CTS 11 on window